# indexPath of UICollectionView change when I scroll down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, indexing, uicollectionview

I have the simple CollectionView, I need to set background cell at index 1 is green, its ok on start (look picture)

but after I scroll down and back I have many green cells? 
what should I do?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {[enter image description here][1]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell
    cell.textMessageLabel.text = arrMes[indexPath.row].textMessage
    cell.dataMessage.text = arrMes[indexPath.row].dataOfMessage

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are reused - hence the call to `dequeueReusableCell()`.

So, you need to set your background to its default color:

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = .white // or whatever your "default" color should be
}
```

---

**Edit** *(after comment)*

Since you are showing "Message" ... think about a "chat" app. The messages may be "from" someone or "to" someone. I assume your data already knows this, so you could do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell

    cell.textMessageLabel.text = arrMes[indexPath.row].textMessage
    cell.dataMessage.text = arrMes[indexPath.row].dataOfMessage

    if arrMes[indexPath.row].fromOrTo == "from" {
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    } 

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is much more. What if I need to set unique content for every cell? Could you help me?

Comment: @DonMag , Thanks a lot, it helps)

Answer (score 0):

As you scroll down, collection view is reusing those cells, that's why you can see more cells with green background. To fix that, you need to set background color for other cells which aren't at index 1.
So for example you can update your function with:

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = .white // your desired color
}
```

or shorter possibility:

```
 cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row == 1 ? .green : .white
```